# How to prevent failedAssertion: size.isFinite in Flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I had a very basic Flutter layout which looked something like this:

```
Column
 widget1
 expanded
 widget2
```

This worked great. Widgets 1 and 2 were rendered and my main "expanded" widget was taking the rest of the screen, great!

Next I wanted to add two buttons on each side of my expanded widget. So I tried this:

```
Column
 widget1
 Row
  button1
  expanded
  button2
 widget2
```

Now Flutter throws a layout error: `failedAssertion: size.isFinite`

Reading about it online, people are saying you cannot put an `Expanded` inside a `Row` or a `Column` because they use infinite main axis length, so if the child is also infinite this causes problems. However, I already had `Expanded` inside a `Column` and that worked fine! Why is putting it inside a `Row` problematic?

One SO suggestion was to put `mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min` in the `Row`, but that does not help.

Some of the other suggestions were to put the widget inside a `Container` with fixed sizes. This does resolve the error, but now the widget goes off screen. And this sort of defies the whole purpose of Flutter responsive UI. Why would anyone want to create a fixed sized object on a platform where screen sizes vary widely?

What am I doing wrong here? Seems I am misunderstanding something fundamental here...

Comment: hey could you add some code for reference so we can determine the solution?

Comment: I am sort of looking for an explanation not a quick fix

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jckqXR5CrPI here's flutter teams explanation about unbounded height and width.

Comment: That's a great video, but it is suggesting I do exactly what I am doing already: use expanded widget. Hang on, I will try to make a reproducible project...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it works fine and doesn't through any error

```
Column(
          children:[
            Container(
                height:50,
                width:50,
                color:Colors.red),
            Row(
                children:[
                  Container(
                      height:50,
                      width:50,
                      color:Colors.red),
                  Expanded(
                      child:Text('hgdhj hdgakhjgck dgfkejg')
                  ),
                  Container(
                      height:50,
                      width:50,
                      color:Colors.red),
                ]),
            Container(
                height:50,
                width:50,
                color:Colors.red),
          ])
```

Comment: Yeah, I am finding that too while trying to create reproducible example, One of the widgets inside expanded is a lottie animation, I wonder if that is not causing problems...

Comment: Nah, even with Lottie I cannot reproduce! Back to drawing board...

Comment: Figured it out I think, There is something inside the expanded widget that was breaking it. There was a stack with a transformation in there. What solved the issue in the end was to wrap the Row inside another Expanded widget.